# Visual Studio 2010 Assembly Signing: An attempt was made to reference a token that does not exist

Tags: code-signing, visual-studio-2010

I'm trying to sign an assembly in Visual Studio 2010 with our PFX file, after I enter the password for the private key I get "An attempt was made to reference a token that does not exist"

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I have the same problem. Just use `signtool` from the Visual Studio command prompt instead. Sometimes `signtool` will claim your password is invalid, but usually after a couple of tries it starts working for me.

`signtool.exe sign /f YOURCERT.pfx /p YOURPASSWORD YOURTARGET.exe`

Comment: Perfect worked as a post build step, just had to change to
signtool.exe sign /f YOURCERT.pfx /p YOURPASSWORD YOURTARGET.exe

Comment: I had crazy problems with this too, eventually had to import the PFX into my local computer store and use this in the post-build:

"%ProgramFiles%\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin\signtool.exe" sign /a /n "Your CN" /sm /t http://timestamp.comodoca.com/authenticode "$(TargetPath)"

Comment: How do you do this with ClickOnce and manifest signing?  Don't you have to sign it during the build for that to work?

Comment: Works great. BTW, it's a good idea to additionally timestamp your exe. Your certificate provider normally will provide you an URL for a timestamping server (e.g. http:\\timestamp.digicert.com) . Then it goes like this:

`signtool.exe sign /f YOURCERT.pfx /t YOURTIMESERVERURL /p YOURPASSWORD YOURTARGET.exe`

Comment: For the ClickOnce bits:
**mage.exe" -sign $(TargetPath).manifest -CertFile  $(ProjectDir)MyPfx.pfx -Password MyPwd**
* mage.exe" -sign $(TargetDir)$(TargetName).vsto -CertFile $(ProjectDir)MyPfx.pfx -Password MyPwd

Answer (score 29):

Running Visual Studio as Administrator fixed this issue for me.

Answer (score 14):

If you want Visual Studio to automatically sign the files and work with [ClickOnce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ClickOnce), this is what I had to do:

- Get a copy of [OpenSSL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenSSL). It is [available for Windows](http://www.slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html). Or use a Linux box as they all pretty much all have it.
- Run the following to export to a key file:

  ```
  openssl pkcs12 -in certfile.pfx -out backupcertfile.key

  openssl pkcs12 -export -out certfiletosignwith.pfx -keysig -in backupcertfile.key
  ```

Then in the project properties you can use the PFX file.

Comment: Identical to [an answer to *Cannot import the keyfile 'blah.pfx' - error 'The keyfile may be password protected'*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2815366/cannot-import-the-keyfile-blah-pfx-error-the-keyfile-may-be-password-protec/8130302#8130302).

Comment: All that did was change the error message.  Now it says the MD5 sum is wrong.

Comment: @Beached: It worked for me, but an explanation of what is happening here would be nice. I'm not familiar with openssl or the pkcs12 command.

Comment: Thanks for this, it's still helping people out in 2020!

Comment: Excellent. After trying so many other methods, this worked for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

This is what worked for me.

First try to build your project with the Key signing option enabled for your project. The build will fail, goto the 'Output' window and you'll see an error like:

> Error 1   Cannot import the following key file: MyKey.pfx. The
>   key file may be password protected. To correct this, try to import the
>   certificate again or manually install the certificate to the Strong
>   Name CSP with the following key container name:
>   VS_KEY_7B9423FE45F4DBEB   Project.SomeName

Save the Key Store name (e.g. VS_KEY_7B9423FE45F4DBEB), you will need this later.

Now follow these steps:

1. Import the digital certificate key (PFX) in the Windows Certificate Store. Double click the PFX key in Windows Explorer and install/import it into your key store (I actually imported it into the trusted root certificates store by selecting manually choose store).
2. Start Visual Studio 2010 as regular user (I don't face this key signing issue as an Administrator, but I want to debug my apps as a user) (keep it open through this entire process)
3. From the Start Menu open the `Visual Studio Command Prompt (2010)` shortcut (x64 if you on a x64 machine) AS AN ADMINISTRATOR (right click on the Visual Studio 2010 Command Prompt shortcut and select run as Administrator). This should open an administrative command prompt with the Visual Studio environment setup. (not a regular command prompt)
4. In the command prompt, enter `sn -d VS_KEY_xxxx` with Key Store name from error message you saved at the beginning
5. Then enter `sn -i xxx.pfx VS_KEY_xxxx`, enter password when prompted, xxx.pfx if your digital certificate
6. Go back to Visual Studio and rebuild your project