# Signing assemblies with strong name using pfx and visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, strongname, pfx

So here is the problem: We have decided to buy a code signing certificate, we bought one from Godaddy which was in p12 format.

After researching I found out that p12 and pfx is the same thing with a different extension so I renamed it to pfx. I also got spc and p7c files but I don't have a clue what to do with them.

Anyway, I tried to add my certificate to my Visual Studio 2013 solution and here is what I get:

- First I get a password prompt and after I input the password I am
  getting an error saying

  ```
  "An attempt was made to reference a token that does not exist."
  ```
- On my second try to install the pfx I am getting no prompts or error messages at all but when I build I am getting the error

  ```
  "Cannot import the following key file: something.pfx 
  The key file may be password protected.
  To correct this, try to import the certificate again or 
  manually install the certificate to the Strong Name CSP with the following
  key container name: VS_KEY_33FA18307607ECFB"
  ```
- So I am doing that using

  ```
  sn -i something.pfx VS_KEY_33FA18307607ECFB
  ```

  which completes with no errors but when I try
  to build again I am getting the exact same error with the same container name.

  ```
  "Cannot import the following key file: something.pfx ....
  ```

I tried to use the signtool which is what Goddady support recommends as an alternative but although it signs the assembly it does not provide strongnaming which I need.

I also tried to extract the certificate from the pfx to an snk using

```
    sn -p something.pfx key.snk
```

and selected delayed signing but the project didn't build again with even more errors.

Rhetorical question: why is this so hard? So many people have problems with this.

Can someone please help?

Comment: spc is the unix file format for the crl2pkcs7 format. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Signing_an_executable_with_Authenticode

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I have just encountered the same issue and [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/andrekl/strong-name-signing-in-visual-studio-2005-requires-keyspec2-at_signature) saved my bacon!

All I needed to do was recreate my Code Signing cert with KeySpec set to 2 (AT_SIGNATURE) and now VS (2013) imports and signs my assembly without error! :-D

I realize that this is a bit different to your scenario, but I hope this can help in some way ...

Comment: This surely showed me the way. I'll give some extra info for those interested.
What I did, based on the link you provided, is: without re-requesting the cert. with a new CSR I installed it using `certutil -importPFX filename.pfx AT_SIGNATURE` to force the keyspec parameter and then extracted the certificate from the store using MMC. This time the certificate worked with VS. Now I had the strong naming. Then I used the 'signtool.exe' to sign the assemblies and finally added the cert. to Click-Once and so I have all my files displaying our Company's information plus a signed installer. Thanks!

Comment: @Ares no problems! Glad it's now working for you :) Thanks for the information; it's good to know a way to resolve this should we encounter the same thing with an external CA

Comment: I also have a GoDaddy cert and this solution worked for me too (without needing a new CSR).  Interestingly the cert was already working for VBA code, also before implementing this solution I had a few extra steps to complete as outlined here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2815366/cannot-import-the-keyfile-blah-pfx-error-the-keyfile-may-be-password-protec

Comment: @Chris: The old link was http://blogs.msdn.com/b/andrekl/archive/2008/01/08/strong-name-signing-in-visual-studio-2005-requires-keyspec-2-at-signature.aspx, the new link is https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/andrekl/strong-name-signing-in-visual-studio-2005-requires-keyspec2-at_signature. I have added both so that everyone can see how links to archived MSDN blogs have changed.

Comment: @TobiasKnauss I have updated the link in the answer so that it's current for those looking; thank you!

Answer (score 26):

I own a Comodo (.p12) certificate and ran into the same issue and solved it based on @SmithPlatts answer and @Ares comment. Here is a detailed walkthrough for those who are not savvy (like me) with certificates:

1. Open Command Prompt with admin privileges.
2. Type command: `certutil -importPFX "<certFilepath>\<certFilename>.p12" AT_SIGNATURE` (AT_SIGNATURE is what makes this work instead of [Right-click .p12 file]-->'Install PFX')
3. Type a password of your choice.
4. Open mmc.exe with admin privileges, File-->Add/Remove Snap-in...
5. Add 'Certificates'
6. Choose 'Computer Account'
7. Under Console Root/Certificates (Local Computer)/Personal/Certificates locate your certificate installed by step 2.
8. Right click Cert/All Tasks/Export-->Next/Yes, export the private key
9. Go to 'Personal Information Exchange - PKCS #12 (.PFX)'
10. Uncheck 'Include all certificates...'. Important! If checked VS will produce this message: "Cannot find the certificate and private key for decryption" when signing.
11. Check 'Export all extended properties' (Optional).
12. You can check 'Delete the private key...' if you are not planning to re-export in the future.
13. Tick password and type the password of step 3.
14. Choose file path and file name for the exported (.pfx) certificate.
15. Use exported .pfx file to sign your assembly/project from VS.
16. Build project to make sure that pfx works properly.

Comment: That did it!  Most importantly I was missing the step to un-check "Include all certificates..."

Comment: I tried this in VS 2015, but I still get the same error

Comment: I tried this too but after I exported the certificate AT_SIGNATURE was overwritten with AT_KEYEXCHANGE...

Comment: You are my hero!

Answer (score 9):

I had this problem and fixed it by opening Visual Studio as an Administrator.

Comment: You may have to grant yourself access to the private key if you put it in the Local Machine certificate store.  I've found this to be true even if you're a local administrator on the PC.

Answer (score 3):

I solved this problem recreating the PFX using openssl with the -keysig option.

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -out "MyPfx.pfx" -keysig -inkey "MyKey.key" -in "MyCer.cer"
```

Answer (score 1):

Was running into this issue as well as perhaps related issues people have alluded to.

Working in a corporate environment in a development department within a larger IT department, I don't have complete local admin permissions. As such when I run VS it doesn't run as local administrator.

Once I set up my shortcut to run VS 2013/2015, the issues I was seeing with singing an assembly...disappeared.

This too might save someone time, as well as from pulling out their hair from their roots.

Comment: This solution worked for me.  Just running VS as Admin,  try the easy solution first!