# Cannot import PFX - Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate

Tags: visual-studio-2013, code-signing

### Problem

So I've been getting an error when trying to use a previously working .PFX to sign the assembly of my code within Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate.

The error in question is
[image]

I have researched this thouroughly before posting this question.

### Steps I have tried

All resolutions relevant to me in this [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2815366/cannot-import-the-keyfile-blah-pfx-error-the-keyfile-may-be-password-protec). The question is 4 years old, any further known resolutions I can try?

I was thinking perhaps just wiping all trace of the certificate from Visual Studio and my PC? How would I go about doing that?

My Signing settings.

[image]

Comment: Are you using this cert in conjunction with a ClickOnce manifest?

Comment: @vcsjones see my updated question for what it looks like.