# "Cannot import the following key file" error when building WPF project on another machine

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, code-signing

I am trying to publish a WPF App on a different computer and a get the following error:

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets (1970):
Cannot import the following key file: KEY.pfx.
The key file may be password protected.

To correct this, try to import the certificate again or manually install the certificate to the Strong Name CSP with the following key container name: VS_KEY_C00C673BBB353901

C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets (1970):
Importing key file "KEY.pfx" was canceled.
```

I tried to fix it by changing Signing options but nothing works,someone knows how to resolve the problem?

Comment: Do you have KEY.pfx in the same directory location on both machines?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cannot import the keyfile 'blah.pfx' - error 'The keyfile may be password protected'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2815366/cannot-import-the-keyfile-blah-pfx-error-the-keyfile-may-be-password-protec) , given the circumstances and information you provided, I consider this a duplicate.