# Jenkins Cannot import the following key file

Tags: jenkins, msbuild, command-prompt, pfx

I am able to build my application on Visual Studio without any problem. I am trying Jenkins out on the same machine. When I try to build my application from my git remote repository (It contains the .pfx file in the SVC) I get the error

> error MSB3325: Cannot import the following key file: Key.pfx. The key
>   file may be password protected. To correct this, try to import the
>   certificate again or manually install the certificate to the Strong
>   Name CSP with the following key container name: VS_KEY...
>
> error MSB3321: Importing key file "Key.pfx" was canceled.

I had already run the command shown on the answer of this question [Cannot import the keyfile 'blah.pfx' - error 'The keyfile may be password protected'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2815366/cannot-import-the-keyfile-blah-pfx-error-the-keyfile-may-be-password-protec) and that is the reason my application runs in Visual Studio (I've done it through the command prompt as administrator fyi), which means when I try running it again the object already exists and if I uninstall and reinstall the same problem happens again.

Anyone has any ideas of how I can solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its the IIDentity (the windows account/identity) that is running Jenkins, most likely.

As a quick test, edit the Jenkins service and put in your credentials.

..

If that works, either keep it that way, or do your manual import voodoo using the identity that you want Jenkins to run under.